# Install npm on mac high sierra

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, homebrew

I want install node.js and npm on mac high sierra.
https://gist.github.com/rcugut/c7abd2a425bb65da3c61d8341cd4b02d
i success install node.js by homebrew, but can't install NPM
how can i do?

---

```
Hoyeongui-MacBook-Air:~ hoyeongkim$ node -v
v8.9.1
Hoyeongui-MacBook-Air:~ hoyeongkim$ curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6255  100  6255    0     0   2628      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  2629
tar=/usr/bin/tar
version:
bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
install npm@latest
fetching: https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-5.5.1.tgz
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/private/var/folders/jn/6wwl3xfd25x94ky333nhcxb80000gn/T/npm.58735/package/bin/read-package-json.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
added 1 package and removed 1 package in 0.846s
/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.9.1/bin/npm -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/8.9.1/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.9.1/bin/npx -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/8.9.1/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
+ npm@5.5.1
updated 1 package in 1.687s
It worked

Hoyeongui-MacBook-Air:~ hoyeongkim$ npm
-bash: npm: command not found
```

Comment: HTH https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks, but it not works..

Comment: Why don’t you want to install npm through Homebrew? That’s the simplest solution: `brew install node`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have looked at this in more detail. I installed `node` with **homebrew** and set my PATH to have `/usr/local/bin` at the very start so I pick up all the **homebrew** binaries.

So, if I check which binary and which version of `node`, I see I am running the one installed by **homebrew**:

```
which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

and that it is the version **homebrew** installs:

```
node -v
v8.9.1
```

The **homebrew** installation of `node` has also automatically installed `npm` just exactly the same:

```
which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
```

and that is also current:

```
npm -v
5.5.1
```

So, I am not sure why you tried to install `npm` from source - just use the one provided by **homebrew**.

---

If I look at the files associated with **homebrew**'s installation of `node`, I can see it includes `npm`:

```
brew ls node --verbose | grep 'npm$'
```

**Sample Output**

```
/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.9.1/etc/bash_completion.d/npm
/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.9.1/libexec/bin/npm
/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.9.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like installing node/npm via brew is becoming more and more problematic. 
As mentioned on this page: http://www.alickwong.com/2017/07/06/npm-command-not-found-mac/ its better to directly install the Mac pkg